# Single quote issue

Tags: sql-server

I have to update a column where I am giving query which is

```
Update Table 
Set col = '[189] IS NOT NULL and [189] <> ''' 
Where colid= 198
```

But it's giving output:-     `[189] IS NOT NULL and [189] <> '`

I want output    :-     `[189] IS NOT NULL and [189] <> ''`

I am not getting single quotes at last. Please let me know how to give update query?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

For each single quote you want in a string constant, you need to use two to represent it

Two quotes in the string requires you to use 4 like this:

```
Update Table Set col = '[189] IS NOT NULL and [189] <> ''''' Where colid= 198
```

Comment: Thanks gbn for your quick reply....It works exactly as I wanted..

Thank you very much.....